# How do I assign a specific role to each newly registered user?

Tags: users, 8

Is it possible in Drupal 8 to assign a specific role to each newly registered user?

Answer (score 7):

I had to implement a similar feature in a site, where:

- Users are not required to verify their email address
- When users create an account, they get the *unverified account* role
- Once the users verify their email address, the *unverified account* role
  is removed, and they get a *confirmed user* role

It is pretty similar to what drupal.org does nowadays; I am just using different roles, and custom code that is different from what drupal.org uses.

I didn't use the [Auto Assign Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module, since there isn't a working version for Drupal 8. I didn't use the [Registration Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_role) module, since it adds the roles to every account being edited, including the accounts with the *administrator* role.

I used a custom module (which I was already using for other purposes), where I implemented [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.2.x) with code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_user_presave(UserInterface $user) {
  if ($user->isNew() && !$user->hasRole('unverified account')) {
    $admin = FALSE;

    foreach ($user->getRoles(TRUE) as $id) {
      $role = Role::load($id);
      if ($role->isAdmin()) {
        $admin = TRUE;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!$admin) {
      $user->addRole('unverified account');
    }
  }
}
```

[`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.6.x) and [`hook_entity_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/8.6.x) are the wrong hooks to use, since they are invoked when the entity is already saved in the database. Calling the `save()` method on the entity passed to those hooks will cause all the hooks invoked when an entity is saved to be invoked again, causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 6):

You could implement [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.2.x).

It will act before the entity is created, So you dont have to save the entity second time at your own risk, save will be manipulated by the core itself just add it in presave hook as mentioned.

```
function modulename_user_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
 if($entity->isNew()) {
   $entity->addRole('rolename');
 }
}
```

You could also use the [Registration Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_role) module.

> Registration role lets an administrator select a role to automatically assign to new users. The selected role will be assigned to new registrants.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning some role to **newly** registered users makes it possible to have features, functions, etc., that would be specific to NEWLY registered users. Like links to some "getting started" topics (e.g. in a block, or some menu links), which you don't want to show anymore to (eg) users that were registered X months ago, right?

IMO there are at least 2 ways of doing so, as further detailed below.

## Auto Assign Role

This is what you could do using the **[Auto Assign Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole)** module ... From its project page:

> The Auto Assign Role serves three primary purposes. The first is to provide an automatic assignment of roles when a new account is created ...

This module is available for D6 and D7, for D8 you'll have to wait for [issue #2220653](https://www.drupal.org/node/2220653), which includes a link to a [sandbox project](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/deepakaryan1988/2412019) about it that you might want to look at ...

## Rules

It's pretty forward to implement this functionality using the **[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)** module, at least in D7.

That would be my recommended approach. Because assuming you have rules installed for other modules, you don't need another module to be added, so it reduces the risk about *modulitis* (= way too much modules enabled)

Though for using [Rules in D8](http://d8rules.org/) it's also too early (work in progress). But, modules with "*many reported installs*", often get more attention (and assigned resources) to be upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8), which is invoked after data is saved in the database.

```
function MY_MODULE_user_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  $entity->addRole('myrolestring'); //no rid!
  $entity->save();
}
```

You could probably also use [`hook_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_presave/8.2.x) instead of `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`. I didn't test this, though.

Comment: Yes, this does work in "hook_entity_insert" as well

Comment: hook_user_insert() is more appropriate than hook_user_presave() since I believe the prior executes only when an user registers and the latter is executed each time the user entity is saved (even after registration).